# Why <p:inputText> not fill in data in bean

Tags: jsf

I have some JSF page and some manage bean. In manage bean I create some odel file and try to fill it by JSF. But it doesn't setup values in. But when i use existing model object in works great.

Here is my JSF code:

```
 <h:form>           
            <c:set var="patient" value="#{manageBean.patient}" />
            <p:panel id="panel" header="Patient" style="margin-bottom:10px;">  
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                    <h:outputLabel value="First  name" />  
                    <p:inputText id="firstName" required="true" value="#{patient.firstName}" />  

                    <h:outputLabel value="Family  name" />  
                    <p:inputText id="familyName" required="true" value="#{patient.familyName}" />  

                    <h:outputLabel value="Sex"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="sex" rendered="true" value="#{patient.sex}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="male" />  
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="female" />  
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Birthday date" />  
                    <p:calendar value="#{patient.birthdayDate}" mode="inline" id="birthdayDate"/>  

                    <h:outputLabel value="Nationality"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="nationality" rendered="true" value="#{patient.nationality}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Russian" itemValue="russian" />  
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ukranian" itemValue="ukranian" />  
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Adress" />  
                    <p:inputText id="adress" required="true" value="#{patient.adress}" />  

                    <h:outputLabel value="Phone number" />  
                    <p:inputMask id="phoneNumber" required="true" value="#{patient.phoneNumber}" mask="(999) 999-9999"/>
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:panel> 
            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{manageBean.save}" />  
        </h:form>
```

And there is my ManageBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "manageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ManageBean implements Serializable {

    private Patient patient;
    private SessionFactory factory;

    public ManageBean() {
        factory = SessionFactoryWrap.getInstance();
    }

    public Patient getPatient() {
        patient = (Patient) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("patient");
        if (patient == null) {
            //patient = new Patient("", "", Sex.male, new Date(), Nationality.ukranian, "", "");
            patient = new Patient();
        }
        return patient;
    }

    public String save() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(patient);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        patient=null;
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("patient", null);
        return "go_home";

    }
}
```

Comment: Things to address here: `<c:set var="patient" value="#{manageBean.patient}" />` is unnecessary. The fact that `#{managedBean.patient}` exists means that you can access it just like that without JSTL.  2. Unless you've simply decided to not show us, there is no setter for `patient`. Nothing will be saved to the backing bean during model update without the setter. Your whole approach in `getPatient()` is all wrong and confusing. You have `<c:set/>` a `pageScoped` car `patient` and in your backing bean, you're retrieving it from the session?? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I send here patient object from other page, and whrn i get object from secession it work good

Comment: @kolossus: the setter for `patient` is not necessary. JSF/EL calls setters in `patient` itself. E.g. `managedBean.getPatient().setFirstName(firstName)`. The problem is indeed in the getter. It's overriding the initial value everytime and hence all submitted values are lost.

Comment: I founded that bug ty man a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you could solve the problem would be to not using any parameter at all and just binding the `UIInput` components to your attribute directly:

```html
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="panel" header="Patient" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="First  name" />
            <p:inputText id="firstName" required="true"
                value="#{manageBean.patient.firstName}" />
<!-- rest of JSF/Facelets code... -->
</h:form>
```

Also, following JSF best practices, you could redefine your managed bean in two ways (as far as I can see atm):

- You don't need to have the `@SessionScoped` annotation in order to handle ajax requests, also it would mean that the constructor (and the `@PostConstruct` method) will be called only once **per session**. The best option for this case would be the `@ViewScoped` annotation. More info: [Managed Bean Scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes).
- You must not have any business logic in your getter/setter method because it will be executed for every `#{managedBean.property}` in your JSF code, more info: [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197). Knowing this, it would be better to load the session data just once in the bean constructor or in the `@PostConstruct` method.

With all this, your managed bean should look like:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "manageBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ManageBean implements Serializable {

    private Patient patient;
    private SessionFactory factory;

    public ManageBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //it would be better to initialize everything here
        factory = SessionFactoryWrap.getInstance();
        patient = (Patient)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
            getSessionMap().get("patient");
        if (patient == null) {
            patient = new Patient();
        }
    }

    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }

    public String save() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(patient);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //in my opinion, it would be better to show a descriptive message
            //instead of returning to the `go_home` view in case of errors.
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        //clumsy code line, no need to have it at all
        //patient = null;
        //Don't set the parameter to null, instead remove it from the session map.
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
            getSessionMap().remove("patient");
        return "go_home";

    }
}
```

Comment: Aswesom ideas thanks a lot, took a bigger part from your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
<c:set var="patient" value="#{manageBean.patient}" />
```

to:

```
<ui:param name="patient" value="#{manageBean.patient}" />
```

This way, you put it in a [Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info) variable and you will be able to reference it for both get and set later on.

Then, put the initialization of the patient object in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method, like so:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    patient = new Patient(); // this will execute every tyme the bean is initialized
}
```

And then just use normal getters and setters (no custom code) for the patient property.